# How to persist data inside div that appended on button click in JSP using JavaScript, Spring Boot?

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-boot, jsp, jpa

I have a dropdown list of cities and a button to add city into vendor model. So I want to add selected city name inside div when button clicked each time. **For example, I have list of cities in dropdown and suppose I selected Bangalore and when clicked on add button then it should get added inside div and when I refresh the page, div list should be persistence.** Which means, when page get reload or refreshed then added city should be displayed inside a div. Currently what I am suffering from is when I reload page then the cities I added after button clicked, gets emptied each time. So I want help regarding this. **Any suggestions would be helpful for me**.

Below is my api controller code to save selected city into database:

```
@RequestMapping(value = AkApiUrl.setdeliverycity, method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET }, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<?> setdeliverycity(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session, @RequestParam("delivercityid") String  delivercityid, 
            @RequestParam("vendorid") String  vendorid) {
        CustomResponse = ResponseFactory.getResponse(request);
        try {
            User loginuser = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
            Long vid = Long.parseLong(vendorid);
            User vendor = userDao.findByUserid(vid);   
            String vendorname = vendor.getName();
            Long cid = Long.parseLong(delivercityid);
            DeliveryCity city = deliverycityDao.findByDelivercityid(cid); 
            VendorCity vendorCity = new VendorCity();
            vendorCity.setVendorcity(city);
            vendorCity.setName(vendorname);
            vendorCity.setVendorid(vendor);
            vendorCity.setCreatedby(loginuser);
            VendorCity delivercity = vendorcitydao.save(vendorCity);
            if (delivercity != null) {
                CustomResponse.setResponse(delivercity);
                CustomResponse.setStatus(CustomStatus.OK);
                CustomResponse.setStatusCode(CustomStatus.OK_CODE);
                CustomResponse.setResponseMessage(CustomStatus.SuccessMsg);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            CustomResponse.setResponse(null);
            CustomResponse.setStatus(CustomStatus.Error);
            CustomResponse.setStatusCode(CustomStatus.Error_CODE);
            CustomResponse.setResponseMessage(CustomStatus.ErrorMsg);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<ResponseDao>(CustomResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Below is script for button click to add cities into div when Ajax success:

```
function addcity(){
        var vendorid = document.getElementById('vendordeliveryid').value; 
        var delivercityid = document.getElementById('vendorcitydd').value;
        var url = "../api/setdeliverycity";
        $.post(url,{
            delivercityid : delivercityid,
            vendorid : vendorid,
        }, function(data, status) {
            if (data.status == "OK") {
                if (data.statusCode == 1) {
                    debugger
                    console.log(data.response);
                    var vendor = data.response;
                    var vid = vendor.vendorcityid;
                    var city = vendor.vendorcity.city;
                    var citydiv = "";   
                    var cityid = vendor.vendorcity.delivercityid;
                    var citylistlength = city.length;
                    if(citylistlength > 0) {
                        citydiv = citydiv+"<div>"+city+" &nbsp;<i class=\"fa fa-times\" onclick=\"removecity('"+cityid+"')\"></i></div>";
                    }else{
                        citydiv = citydiv+"<div style=\"text-align: center; float: left; margin-left: 40%; font-size: medium; font-weight: bolder; background: blanchedalmond;\"><span>Choose city from list</span></div>";
                    }
                    $('#citydivid').append(citydiv);
                    $('#cid').val(cityid);
                    $('#vendorcityid').val(vid);
                } else {
                    var error = data.responseMessage;
                    swal(error, "", "error");
                }
            } else {
                var error = data.responseMessage;
                swal(error, "", "error");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You can save select-box selected value in LocalStorage . Then whenever your page `reload` you can check if there is any value inside localStorage or not depending on that call your function on page load to populate div .

Comment: Hi Swati, can you please show some example to do in that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check on page load if there is any data inside your *localStorage* or not  .If yes you can get that datas and call your ajax to execute further codes and inside this ajax call if data are successfully appended inside your *DOM* your can clear previous data and save new data i.e : vendorid..etc inside *localStorage*.

Here , is ***sample code*** which should work :

```
 $(function() {
  //check if the localStorage is not null
  if (localStorage.getItem("delivercityid") != null) {
    var delivercityid = localStorage.getItem("delivercityid"); //get that value
    var vendorid = localStorage.getItem("vendorid");
    ajax_call(vendorid, delivercityid); //call function
    localStorage.clear(); //clear from here after page load..
  }

});

function addcity() {
  var vendorid = document.getElementById('vendordeliveryid').value;
  var delivercityid = document.getElementById('vendorcitydd').value;
  ajax_call(vendorid, delivercityid)
}

function ajax_call(vendorid, delivercityid) {
  var url = "../api/setdeliverycity";
  $.post(url, {
    delivercityid: delivercityid,
    vendorid: vendorid,
  }, function(data, status) {
    if (data.status == "OK") {
      if (data.statusCode == 1) {
        debugger
        console.log(data.response);
        var vendor = data.response;
        //..
        //other codes..
        localStorage.setItem("vendorid", vendorid);
        var delivercityid_datas = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("delivercityid")) || []; //all datas
        delivercityid_datas.push(delivercityid); //push new data inside localstorage
        localStorage.setItem("delivercityid", JSON.stringify(delivercityid_datas)); //reinitalze again
      } else {
        var error = data.responseMessage;
        swal(error, "", "error");
      }
    } else {
      var error = data.responseMessage;
      swal(error, "", "error");
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: Thank you Swati. Above code somewhat fulfils requirement but the thing is when I am selecting more than one option and clicking on addcity button and after page refresh, it is retaining last selected values. How should I do same when I want to display all selected items inside div. I hope you understands my question.

Comment: Here , which value is of dropdown and which is constant value ?

Comment: Scenario is simple, I want to add cities in which vendor deliver things (as an example). So one vendorid can have multiple cities. Therefore, I have an add button and list of cities dropdown. So, when I select more than one options (and of course those should get appended inside div on each ajax call). After page reload, all those cities of div should be retained.
Constant value is vendorid and dropdown value can be different (according to choice single vendor can have multiple cities).

Comment: Can you manipulate your backend if values for dropdown are send as array ? Maybe using split and all ? Because , there will be so many records if you will call them one by one it will take time to load all datas so if i add them in array and send in it one go it would be easy . If you can do that i can update my answer with that option .

Comment: Yes, I am trying it from backend to get list of cities for particular vendor id.

Comment: Yes  then ,even if you have `vendor id` it should work as well. I will update my code with array option as well .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233916/discussion-between-swati-and-rakhi-sharma).